# Configurar domínio para estrutura de página Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, htaccess, apache

Tenho uma instalação Wordpress com vários "sites".. vou explicar:

> site-principal.com/ -> abre uma página em branco (index.php, sem nenhum redirecionamento em opções/leitura)
>
> site-principal.com/site-um -> Página Wordpress 'Site Um', com suas respectivas subpáginas: site-principal.com/site-um/contato ; site-principal.com/site-um/clientes
>
> site-principal.com/site-dois -> Página Wordpress 'Site Dois', com suas respectivas subpáginas: site-principal.com/site-dois/parceiros ; site-principal.com/site-dois/clientes

E tenho os domínios:

site-um.com >> precisa ir para a página >> site-principal.com/site-um

site-dois.com >> precisa ir para a página >> site-principal.com/site-dois

Minha pergunta é: como eu faço essa configuração, não é apenas um redirecionamento, a URL precisa ser site-um.com abrindo a partir da página Wordpress /site-um/

Já fiz redirecionamento de subdomínio para diretórios, mas não para páginas.

Htaccess, subdominios, apache, CNAME... qual caminho devo tomar?

Obrigado!

Comment: Realize a pergunta em português.

Comment: Feito! Obrigado pelo retorno :)

Comment: Você tem uma instancia multisites? Você tem vários WPs instalados em diferentes pastas respondendo à um mesmo domínio? Tá dificil entender...

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress tem função nativa para multi sites, se fez a configuração desta forma
basta seguir estas instruções 
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/howto-domain-mapping-without-a-plugin-instructions/

Comment: Evite comentar apenas link para uma possível solução. Links podem ser editados ou removidos com o tempo e isso inutiliza sua resposta. Descreva o que o link propõe e referencie ele.